# Getting "Future attached to a different loop" Error in Singleton with asyncio

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, python-asyncio, fastapi

I've implemented a singleton pattern in Python to manage WebSocket connections using FastAPI and asyncio. However, I'm encountering a "Future pending attached to a different loop" error, specifically when dealing with the asyncio.Lock() in my ConnectionManager class.

Here's the error message:

```
cb=[WebSocketProtocol.on_task_complete()]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

**Code Details**

- *endpoint.py*: This file contains the ConnectionManager class which manages WebSocket connections. It uses asyncio.Lock() to handle active_conversations.
- *main.py*: Sets up the FastAPI application and includes the WebSocket routes.
- *test.js*: I'm also using k6 for load testing the WebSocket connections.

**Code Snippets**

`endpoint.py`

```
import logging
import asyncio
from asyncio import Lock
from dataclasses import dataclass
import json

from fastapi import APIRouter, HTTPException, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect
from fastapi.param_functions import Query


# Router
router = APIRouter()

# Logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@dataclass
class Connection:
    websocket: WebSocket


class ConnectionManager:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(ConnectionManager, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        if not hasattr(self, "initialized"):
            self.active_conversations: dict[str, Connection] = {}
            self.lock = Lock()
            self.initialized = True

    async def connect(self, websocket: WebSocket, session_id: str):
        async with self.lock:
            await websocket.accept()

            connection = Connection(websocket=websocket)
            self.active_conversations[session_id] = connection

    async def disconnect(self, session_id: str):
        async with self.lock:
            connection = self.active_conversations.pop(session_id, None)

            # Sleep 1 second
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

            if not connection:
                return

            # Attempt to close the WebSocket connection
            try:
                await connection.websocket.close()
                logger.info(f"WebSocket closed for session {session_id}")
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Error closing WebSocket for session {session_id}: {e}")


manager = ConnectionManager()


@router.websocket("/conversation/{session_id}")
async def conversation(websocket: WebSocket, session_id: str, token: str = Query(...)):
    if not token:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Token is required!")

    try:
        await manager.connect(websocket=websocket, session_id=session_id)

        # Listen for messages
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            message = json.loads(data)

            # Handle ping message
            if message.get("type") == "ping":
                await websocket.send_text(json.dumps({"type": "pong"}))

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in WebSocket connection: {e}")
    finally:
        await manager.disconnect(session_id=session_id)
```

`main.py`

```
import os

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from jac.api.endpoints import router as endpoint_router

app = FastAPI(title="Deepdive LLM")

# Add CORS middleware
origins = ["*"]
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

app.include_router(endpoint_router)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

`test.js`

```
import ws from 'k6/ws';
import { check } from 'k6';

export const options = {
    scenarios: {
        warmup: {
            executor: 'per-vu-iterations',
            vus: 5,
            iterations: 1,
            maxDuration: '2m',
        },
    },
};
export default function () {
    const url = 'ws://localhost:8080/conversation/session_' + __VU;  // Replace with your server URL
    const token = 'your_token';  // Replace with your token
    const connection = `${url}?token=${token}`;

    const response = ws.connect(connection, {}, function (socket) {
        socket.on('open', function open() {
            console.log('connected');
            socket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'ping', session_id: 'session_' + __VU, token: token }));

            socket.on('message', function (msg) {
                console.log('Message received: ', msg);
                check(msg, { 'is pong': (msg) => msg.includes('pong') });
                socket.close();
            });

            socket.on('close', () => console.log('disconnected'));
        });

        socket.on('error', function (e) {
            if (e.error() != 'websocket: close sent') {
                console.error('An unexpected error occured: ', e.error());
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The probable thing about this issue is the existing different event loops and a specific lock associated with an event loop!

Therefore, to resolve this issue, you should ensure that the lock is associated with the correct event loop properly.

Here's the updated `ConnectionManager` to do that:

```py
class ConnectionManager:
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(ConnectionManager, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        if not hasattr(self, "initialized"):
            self.active_conversations: dict[str, Connection] = {}
            self.lock = None  # Note
            self.initialized = True

    async def get_lock(self):  # Note
        if self.lock is None:
            self.lock =asyncio.Lock()
        return self.lock

    async def connect(self, websocket: WebSocket, session_id: str):
        lock = await self.get_lock()  # Note
        async with lock:  # Note
            await websocket.accept()
            connection = Connection(websocket=websocket)
            self.active_conversations[session_id] = connection

    async def disconnect(self, session_id: str):
        lock = await self.get_lock()  # Note
        async with lock:  # Note
            connection = self.active_conversations.pop(session_id, None)
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            if not connection:
                return
            try:
                await connection.websocket.close()
                logger.info(f"WebSocket closed for session {session_id}")
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Error closing WebSocket for session {session_id}: {e}")
```

In fact, with the above code, you would have a lazy lock.